# How to replace every 2nd tab character with a newline character using sed

Tags: sed

given the input

`123\t456\tabc\tdef`

create the output

`123\t456\nabc\tdef`

which would display like

```
123    456
abc    def
```

Note that it needs to work across multiple lines, not just two.

**EDIT**

a better example might help clarify.

input (there is only expected to be 1 line of input)

```
1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8
```

expected output

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
...
```

Comment: What if you have input with two lines and with three tabs in each line. How many lines should be in the output? In other words, you want to replace every second tab per line or per file?

Comment: @TimofeyChernousov there should be 4 lines in the output in that case. the only rule is that every 2nd tab character needs to be replaced with a newline. all other characters are left alone.

Comment: @TimofeyChernousov i updated my question to make it a bit clearer...

Comment: @Remover if TimofeyChernousov answer is still not working, it is perhaps because you have sed version that doesn't recognize `\t` or `\n`?

Comment: @Sundeep it seems that way. i'm just using whatever comes as standard with OSX

Comment: thanks to comment from @Sundeep we know that we need this being done with OS X built-in tools. I've updated my answer for this case also.

Answer (score 2):

This little trick should work:

```
sed 's/\(\t[^\t]*\)\t/\1\n/g' < input_file.txt
```

EDIT:
Below is an example:

```
$ cat 1.txt
one     two     three   four    five    six     seven
five    six     seven

$ sed 's/\(\t[^\t]*\)\t/\1\n/g' < 1.txt
one     two
three   four
five    six
seven
five    six
seven

$
```

EDIT2:
For MacOS' standard `sed` try this:

```
$ sed $'s/(\t[^\t]*\t/\\1\\\n/g' < 1.txt
```

`$` is used for replacing escape characters on the bash-level.

Comment: @Remover I have added an example. Is your data significantly different from my example?

Comment: the data is very similar to what you have here. i think it may be as @Sundeep says... maybe i have a version of sed that doesn't recognise these `\t` characters...

Comment: @Remover have you tried Mac version of command above (EDIT2) ?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\t/\n/2;P;D;' file
```

Replaces second occurrence of tab character with newline character.

Comment: i have the OSX version of sed... do you know if it's possible with that?

Comment: Try this:  `sed 's/\t/\'$'\n/2;P;D;'`. For more: [Newlines in sed on Mac](http://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say following is the Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
123     456     abc     def
```

Then to get them into 2 columns following may help you in same.

```
xargs -n2 <  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
123 456
abc def
```

Comment: this doesn't work, unfortunately... i specifically want to replace every second tab with a newline character. that means it should cope with more complex input such as spaces and commas etc.